# Ninject: How to inject 'this' (the containing class) into an instance?

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, constructor-injection

I'm new to Ninject and DI in general.

Let's assume I have a class `Caller`:

```
public class Caller : ICaller, ICallback {

  private ICommand command;

  public Caller(ICommand command) {
    this.command = command;
  }

  //callback method
  public void OnCommandCompleted() { }

}
```

The `Command` looks like this:

```
public class Command : ICommand {

  private ICallback Callback { get; set; }

  public Command(ICallback callback) {
    this.Callback = callback;
  }

  public void Execute() {

    //do something
    this.Callback.OnCommandCompleted();

  }

}
```

The command should have a reference to the class that created/injected it. What would be the appropriate way of doing it? Of course I could remove the dependency from the constructor and instead set it manually:

```
public Caller(ICommand command) {
  command.Callback = this;
  this.command = command;
}
```

But is there another way?

EDIT: To clarify my intention with this design I updated the given code. The `command` gets a callback as dependency which is the `Caller` in my case.

Comment: Why do you require this? This causes cyclic dependencies and these are usually a bad idea, since they increase complexity. Please update your answer with a detailed description on why you need this and show you the related code. This way we can give you feedback on how to fix your design.

Comment: Hey, actually the `Command` requires a `ICallback` as dependency, to inform the caller when it has finished. I updated my example code to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

Like that it's not easily possible.
There's no C# code you could write (replacing the container) to achieve that ctor injection scenario, either:

```
new Caller(new Command(???))
```

==> it's not possible to replace `???` with a reference to the `Caller` being created because it has not been created yet.

To achieve a circular reference you'd have to do something like:

```
var command = new Command();
var caller = new Caller(command);
command.InitializeWithCallback(caller);
```

So I agree with Steven, this looks very much like bad design and should be refacatored so there's no cyclic dependency required. Furthermore, typically containers will not support such a scenario - at ctor time it is not possible to inject a reference because that has yet to be created.

You could, in theory, accomodate your ctor-injection design by injecting an `ICallback` proxy into `Command` and after instanciation of `Caller` initialize the proxy with the `Caller` instance. However, that introduces complexity that's typically absolutely unwarranted. At the end of the day it just bloats your code while you could just as well introduce `Command.InitializeWithCallback(caller)`.

Comment: I don't see this as bad design by definition. Actually it is the observer pattern. But you are right that I wouldn't have it implemented that way without DI (respectively it would not be possible as you pointed out). I decided to simply use an `Event` for my purpose. Didn't took this possibility into account as I'm porting the structure over from Java.